# Get the size of UIButton inside a custom UITableViewCell with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, calayer

I have an UIButton inside a custom UITableViewCell created in Interface Builder, the height and width is defined by Autolayout constraints.

I need to get the size of the UIButton after autolayout define the final size.

[image: UITableViewCell with Autolayout]

what I have tried:

**Inside my custom UITableViewCell**

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews
 {
    [super layoutSubviews];

  NSLog(@"%f", self.infoButton.bounds.size.width);

    self.infoButton.layer.cornerRadius   = self.infoButton.bounds.size.width/2;
    self.infoButton.clipsToBounds        = YES;
    self.infoButton.layer.borderColor    = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.infoButton.layer.borderWidth    = 4.0f;
}
```

The problem is that I have different values :

```
2015-06-30 03:01:47.578 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 48.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:47.581 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 48.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:47.583 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 48.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:47.585 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:47.586 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:47.586 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:53.482 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 48.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:53.484 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:01:54.939 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:02:04.161 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:02:05.115 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
2015-06-30 03:02:05.957 MYPROJ[3596:34092] 56.000000
```

I have also tried the code inside `- (void)awakeFromNib` I tried both `self.infoButton.bounds.size.width` and `self.infoButton.frame.size.width`

and it gives me the static width before Autolayout which is in my case 48.0
Also

I am afraid the solution of putting the code inside `- (void)layoutSubviews` can affect performance since it will be called everything the user scroll and apply the layer transformation every time, is there any better solution ?

Comment: now so updated answwer.!!

Comment: I have tried `self.infoButton.frame.size.width` bt it gives me always the size before autolayout

Comment: Can you provide the horizontal constraints you used for cell's button? That'll help..

Comment: @TejvanshSinghChhabra I have updated the question with an image, actually the width of the UIButton is 15% of the width of the cell also it has a Aspect ratio constraint as you can see from the screenshot

Comment: Does the cell completely fills the screen size horizontally? In that case, its simple to achieve that.

Comment: @TejvanshSinghChhabra Yes the Cell fills the screen horizontally and the image also "Aspect Fill" with "Clip Subviews", basicly I want to make the button which has variant width to be round (circle) in all devices

Comment: I've posted a simple answer, check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom UITableViewCell.m file, add following lines in your awakeFromNib method.

Here, as your button is dependent on cell and which indeed has same width as device's screen.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
self.infoButton.layer.cornerRadius   = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.075f; // 0.15/2 = 0.075f (Half of the button's width)
self.infoButton.clipsToBounds        = YES;
self.infoButton.layer.borderColor    = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.infoButton.layer.borderWidth    = 4.0f;
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: It works, thank you, but I guess that I don't have to change the constraint of the UIButton. Can you explain why `* 0.075f;`

Comment: I've added comment in it to help you understand.. If the answer helped you, mark as correct and upvote, so other can know it..

Comment: Thank you, I have forgot that I need half the width ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the intrinsic content size of your button.

`CGSize buttonSize = self.infoButton.intrinsicContentSize;`

Comment: I have already tried this, but it does not work, it shows wrong values both in `awakeFromNib` and `layoutSubviews`